# Tweet Feels: Always returns the same Sentiment Score, regardless tags

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to use this library to generate sentiment score for cryptocurrencies:

https://github.com/uclatommy/tweetfeels/blob/master/README.md

When I use the code from the example `trump`, it returns a sentiment score of `-0.00082536637608123106`.

I have changed the tags to the following:

```
btc_feels = TweetFeels(login, tracking=['bitcoin'])
btc_feels.start(20)
btc_feels.sentiment.value
```

and it still gives me the same value.

I did notice something strange when I installed the library.

from the instructions:

> If for some reason pip did not install the vader lexicon:
>
> > python3 -m nltk.downloader vader_lexicon

When I ran this, I got:

> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning:
>   'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk',
>   but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in
>   unpredictable behaviour   warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))

Could this be why it appears not to be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, tweetfeels creates a database in your current directory. The next time you start the program, it will continue using the same database, and pick up where it left off. I don't know what tweetfeels does to handle you changing the keyword on it, but this behaviour of tweetfeels could be a problem. The solution would be to use a different database for different keywords, and then pass in the location of your database to the TweetFeels constructor.

I don't know that much about Tweetfeels, it just sounded interesting, so I've downloaded the project, and I have a working script that will perform the sentiment analysis on any keyword I give it. I can add a copy of the script here, if you're still having problems getting TweetFeels to work.

**Edit: here the script I am using**

I am currently having the following problems with the script.

1) I was getting some error that was different from the one you'd got, but I was able to fix the issue by replacing the tweetfeels library from pip with the latest code in their Github repository.

2) If a sentiment value does not get reported, sometimes tweetfeels fails to come to a complete stop, without forcefully sending a ctrl+c keyboard interrupt.

```
import os, sys, time
from threading import Thread
from pathlib import Path

from tweetfeels import TweetFeels

consumer_key = 'em...'
consumer_secret = 'aF...'
access_token = '25...'
access_token_secret = 'd3...'
login = [consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret]

try:
    kw = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    kw = "iota"

try:
    secs = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    secs = 15

for arg in sys.argv:
    if (arg == "-h" or arg == "--help"):
        print("Gets sentiment from twitter.\n"
              "Pass in a search term, and how frequently you would like the sentiment recalculated (defaults to 15 seconds).\n"
              "The keyword can be a comma seperated list of keywords to look at.")
        sys.exit(0)

db = Path(f"~/tweetfeels/{kw}.sqlite").expanduser()
if db.exists():
    print("existing db detected. Continueing from where the last sentiment stream left off")
else:
    #ensure the parent folder exists, the db will be created inside of this folder
    Path(f"~/tweetfeels").expanduser().mkdir(exist_ok=True)

feels = TweetFeels(login, tracking=kw.split(","), db=str(db))

go_on = True
def print_feels(feels, seconds):
    while go_on:
        if feels.sentiment:
            print(f"{feels.sentiment.volume} tweets analyzed from {feels.sentiment.start} to {feels.sentiment.end}")
            print(f'[{time.ctime()}] Sentiment Score: {feels.sentiment.value}')
            print(flush=True)
        else:
            print(f"The datastream has not reported a sentiment value.")
            print(f"It takes a little bit for the first tweets to be analyzed (max of {feels._stream.retry_time_cap + seconds} seconds).")
            print("If this problem persists, there may not be anyone tweeting about the keyword(s) you used")
            print(flush=True)
        time.sleep(seconds)


t = Thread(target=print_feels, kwargs={"feels":feels,"seconds":secs}, daemon=True)
print(f'Twitter posts containing the keyword(s) "{kw}" will be streamed, and a new sentiment value will be recalculated every {secs} seconds')
feels.start()
time.sleep(5)
t.start()

try:
    input("Push enter at any time to stop the feed...\n\n")
except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
    feels.stop()
    raise e

feels.stop()
go_on = False
print(f"Stopping feed. It may take up to {feels._stream.retry_time_cap} for the feed to shut down.\n")
#we're waiting on the feels thread to stop
```

Comment: I've added my script to the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

No, the same sentiment value that you see printed is not related to the warning you've got when downloading the dataset.

The problem with the same sentiment score is coming from [these lines](https://github.com/uclatommy/tweetfeels/blob/master/tweetfeels/tweetfeels.py#L132):

```
for s in sentiments:
    pass
return s
```

I suspect that this unbound variable `s` remembers the previous value of the sentiment score.

But, the problem itself is that you are printing out the score right after you execute the `start()` function which starts a multi-threaded program to constantly update data from twitter - you should not expect the sentiment score to arrive right after you started the update.

Note that the examples in the README are shown from the Python terminal where they wait after the execution of `start()` function until the `Timer completed. Disconnecting now...` message appears.

Comment: I did wait for the time completed message